# Serious Bug:Sublime Text break file when remaining harddisk space isn't enought!!! How can I recover it？

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext, data-recovery, file-recovery

When remaining harddisk space wasn't enough,I tried to close a txt，Sublime Text told me that it can't be save.It's no problem,I only update a little sentence, so I don't care if it's saved.Then I closed it.But the next time,I open the txt, it is empty.I lost all the data.(╯‵□′)╯︵┻━┻
I have used this file to note various things for months.It is broken now! How can I recover it？ (There were 200+ lines text in it yesterday T~T...)
OS: MacOS Sierra
SublimeText: Build 3126

[The left is broken file, the right is another file(not be broken)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRiCw.png)

Comment: Keeping track of unsaved documents also use memory disk as a temporal file... so unfortunately, i think you cant recover it :(

Comment: So we are talking about a text file, with important information in it, used for months... of course you were keeping it in Dropbox, right?

Answer (score 0):

(If you're using Windows):

Find the file on the drive, right-click, and check for "previous versions" of the file. There should be some there, and if one of them opens, you should be fine. And then, maybe make sure that a working drive always have available space...

If on OSX:

You can read it here: support.apple.com/kb/PH18862?locale=en_US 
(Basically, open the file in TextEdit (usually just double click in Finder), go to the File or Archive-tab, and chose "revert file" - then you should see other versions).

No guarantees, though

Comment: I haven't found "previous versions".My OS is MacOS Sierra > <.Is there similar way on MacOS？

Comment: Yes (sort of): you can read it here: https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18862?locale=en_US (Basically, open the file in TextEdit (usually just double click in Finder, go to the File or Archive-tab, and chose "revert file" - then you should see other versions. Updated the answer as well.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.But after clicking "revert file",there is not any other versions,because I'v never saved the file by system text editor,> <.I tried many data recovery software yesterday，maybe I should give up now...restarting Mac...to do new things... T~T